# CSS Layout Problems, FlowChart Design

Tags: javascript, html, css, layout

i need to build a dynamic template to create a flow chart diagram, but only with HTML and CSS

See Image.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nKXrO.png)

- The black DIV should have a defined width and height.
- The red DIV represent a row in the black DIV.
- The green DIV are boxes with a border and a defined size with 100px height and 200px width.
- It should be possible to add two or more green DIVs into one red DIV (See yellow rect)
- All the content should align in the middle (See blue line)

```css
.page {
position: relative;
width: 800px;
height: 800px;
}

.row{
width: 100%;
text-align: center;
margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.element{
 display: inline-block;
 text-align: center;
 width: 200px;
 height: 50px;
 border: 1px solid #000;
 }
```

```html
<div class="page">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="element">Start</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="element">Step_1</div>
    <div class="element">Step_2</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="element">Step_1_2</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="element">Ende</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Maybe someone can help me to implement the layout.
Thank you

Comment: please try at least a couple of css display so we can talk about something ... your edit is a good start, but doesn't help you much more ;)

Comment: try to learn basics of css positioning from https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS

Comment: Sure, your right. But i must fix the problem for a customer and css is not business. And iam run out of time, so your are my last hope to fix the issue.

Comment: Maybe you need a professionnal and charge your customer for this :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are looking for something like this: https://jsfiddle.net/m1pz6zcu/

```
.page {
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
  text-align: center;
}

.row {
  width: calc(100% - 2px);
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-color: red;
  display: flex;
  height: calc(25% - 2px);
}

.element {
  min-width: 20%;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-color: green;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
  height: 50px;
  height: calc(100% - 2px);
}
```